# I am trying to split data into 4 equal sized groups, all data is in 1 column

Tags: excel-formula

I have found a previous thread on here which gives a formula and it does what I need it to beautifully, but only if there are no headers or empty rows above the starting row of data.

With data in column A, in B1 enter:

`=A1 & "," & ROUNDUP(ROW()/(COUNT(A:A)/4),0)`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pcKn.png)

This works amazingly, as there are no headers. But if say, I have a header to my column, and two empty cells above the header, the formula above splits the data into 5 uneqaul groups, with the 5th group having just 3 in the group.

Is there anything I can add to this formula so that it doesnt count the first 3 rows above where the data starts.

I have already tried absolute referencing, for example:

'`=AU4&","&ROUNDUP(ROW()/(COUNT($AU$4:$AU$2522)/4),0)`     but it still presents the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subtract the empty rows from the current row --> `(ROW()-3)` instead of `ROW()`:

```
=A4&","&ROUNDUP((ROW()-3)/(COUNT(A:A)/4),0)
```

Comment: You are the best. Thanks so much, thats worked an absolute treat!!!! Now there's another itteration that we have to look at in another column, but the challenge this time around is not all cells have data in, so i only want it to work on the cells that have data in... is there any way i can do this?

Comment: This sounds like a new question ...